# is this opinion true about "Wrapper Objects" in JS

Tags: javascript

today, i read some articles about "Why Primitive data in javascript have properties and methods like objects"?

after that, i understand that when we call a method or property on a primitive data, JS coerces that to something like this

```js
var str="hello";
console.log(str.toUpperCase());
// => translated to:
var str="hello";
var temp = new String(str);
console.log(temp.toUpperCase());
```

so we called temp as a "Wrapper Object". Once the property has been resolved, the wrapper object is discarded.

also

i know that we can doing this manually and declare a variable like temp ourselves. (of course this object is not discarded).

```js
var one=new Number(1);
console.log(one);
```

my first question. is that object(one) a wrapper Object, too?

and my finally question: **is this sentence true**??

*Wrapper Object is an Object which has a primitive data and some property/method about it. this object can create implicit (by JS automatically) or explicit (by developer)*

Comment: `one` is a wrapper object there, yes. You should never create one, and if you work in strict mode, you’ll also never need to know they exist. They’re an implementation detail that isn’t actually necessary for implementation, and one of JavaScript’s biggest misfeatures.

Comment: @Ry- thank you. but why using this is bad? i thought if i want to call a method on a string 5 times, behind the scene js creates a new wrapper object and discard it 5 times and if i create it myself, i saved 4 times of object building. Was I wrong?

Comment: Yes, that’s wrong. Engines don’t actually create wrapper objects so often.

Comment: @Ry- OK! (don’t actually create wrapper objects so often) so it's an important point that i didn't know. thank you so much!